# synchronizing multiple slaves in an I2C network using dsPIC33EP256GP502

Tags: interrupt, i2c, dspic

[dsPIC33EP syncronisation](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m889896.aspx?tree=true)

Hello,

Can someone explain how can I synchronize multiple slaves in an I2C network using dsPIC33EP256GP502 and the details are attached in the link above.

Thanks and Regards,
Akhil

Comment: Not sure if i understand what kind of sync you are locking for the I2C by definition is a synchronous communication protocol.

Comment: I am trying to develop a master slave network with out using interrupts (tried with interrupts and not getting it). I have dsPIC33EP talking to an another dsPIC33EP and the purpose is to read/write from/to the slave.